# Strip index.php from Magento nginx github configuration

Tags: url-rewrite, nginx, ce-1.9.2.2

I am currently on a Magento-1.9.2.2 with Nginx 1.6.2 and using [Magento Nginx Github Conf](https://github.com/magenx/Magento-nginx-config/blob/master/magento/www/magento.conf) and

shop.com takes me shop.com
But if I click any link, I see a structure like:
shop.com/index.php/category1
shop.com/index.php/product-details-1

How could I get rid of the `index.php` without breaking some other parts of the shop?

```
location / {
            index index.html index.php;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
            expires 30d;
    }

location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
            rewrite / /index.php;
    }
```

Comment: I'm about 99% sure this is a Magento setting called something like "Use Web Server Rewrites", not an nginx setting.

Comment: Oh .. yes, indeed. And I was searching for the problem in the NGinX conf :-S 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to

System->Config->Web->Search Engine Optimization

[image]